# Error when using RewriteRule on the second .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I am developing on my localhost and i have a structure like so:

```
|public_html
|   .htaccess
|   [pagefolder]
|   ......index.php
|   ......[adminfolder]
|   .............htaccess
|   .............admin.php
```

As you can see, i decide it not to go crazy on `.htaccess` files. Just 2 is enough. One on my root and one on my protected admin folder.

when the url is `localhost` i just do the following on my root `.htaccess` to display the initial page:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ pagefolder/index.php [L]
```

When i want to access the admin panel (url: localhost/admin), i just do:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ pagefolder/adminfolder/admin.php [L]
```

So far so good (i think). I run into problems when im using the `.htaccess` in the [adminfolder]

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^award/?$ admin.php?v=award [L,QSA]
```

When i go url: localhost/admin/award i get error:

```
The requested URL /admin/award was not found on this server.
```

However, the rule in the [adminfolder] looks ok to me. Im guessing something is missing, but not sure what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your rules match `/admin/award`.

Your last rule redirects `/pagefolder/adminfolder/award` to `/pagefolder/adminfolder/admin.php?v=award`.

You can fix this by redirecting more `admin` URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)? pagefolder/adminfolder/$0 [L]
```

Then change your `adminfolder` .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/award/?$ admin.php?v=award [L,QSA]
```